# How can I make RABL render an attribute only if it exists in the object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rabl

I have a RESTful User model and am trying to filter attributes to be included in the Show JSON  response when the User object being sought is not the current user.

Logic:

```
if params[:id]==current_user
  json => {:name: <name value>, :birthdate: <birthdate>}
else
  json => {:name: <name value>}
end
```

When I filter attributes in the controller, I get a MissingAttribuiteError with the following code:

*UsersController*

```
def show
  if params[:id]==current_user.id.to_s
    @user=User.find(params[:id])
  else
    @user=User.find(params[:id], :select => [:name])
  end
  respond_with(@user)
end
```

*users/show.json.rabl*

```
object @user
attributes :name, :birthdate
```

How can I make RABL render an attribute only if it exists in the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently easy things should be easy. This works.

[Not sure if filtering on the view level is better or worse than filtering in the controller, though.]

*UsersController*

```
def show
    @user=User.find(params[:id])
    respond_with(@user)
end
```

*users/show.json.rabl*

```
if @user==current_user
  attributes :birthdate
end
```